# call a 'def' with an 'input' in Python

Tags: python, function

I'm working on a project, and I got a bit stuck. I want the user the of the program to be able to call a function. But it must be easy for the user to call it. For example

```
def definition():
    print("This is a function")
command = input("> ")
if command == definition:
    definition()
else:
    print("")
```

in this function I want the user not to write the () in the input. But I want the user just to be able to write 'definition' to call the function. Does anyone have any clue how to do this?

Comment: You're comparing the input to *the function itself*, did you mean `== "definition"`?

Comment: `command` is a string, and `definition` is a function. The comparison will always give `False`. This will not work. You should compare it to `"definition" `, a string.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the quotes from around definition, therefore trying to compare an undeclared variable with an inputted string which will always equate to false.

Try:

```py
def definition():
    print("This is a function")

command = input("> ")

if command == 'definition':
    definition()
else:
    print("")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up the function name (callable object in you code) and the name from your input.

For your problem I would use a dictionary of function names for the keys and function references for the value

```
def function1():
    print ('calling function1')

def function2():
    print ('calling function2')

def function3():
    print ('calling function3')

functions = {}
functions['function1'] = function1
functions['function2'] = function2
functions['function3'] = function3

name = input('Enter the function name:\n')
if name in functions:
    functions[name]()
else:
    print ('Invalid function name. Use one of: ')
    for key in functions.keys():
        print ('  - ' + key)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implicitly define the conditions with if statement..

For ease of user you can do like this:

```
def definition():
       #your function here
if __name__=='__main__':
 print ("Choose your option:\n1. Definition")
 choice = int(input("Enter choice: "))
if choice == 1:
 definition ()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just one command "definition"

```
def definition():
    print("This is a function")

command = input("> ")

if command == "definition":
    definition()
else:
    print("Wrong command !")
```

More commands and functions

```py
def definition():
    print("This is definition function")

def modify():
    print("This is modify function")

func = {"definition":definition, "modify":modify}
command = input("> ").strip().lower()

if command in func:
    func[command]()
else:
    print("Wrong command !")
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
whitelist_funcs = ['definition', 'something else']
command = input("> ")
if command in whitelist_funcs:
    exec(f"{command}()")
else:
    print("")
```

Comment: Exec (and/or eval) is almost never the right way to deal with user input.